# 重複組み合わせ・CSVファイルへの記載方法

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

Ruby初心者です．
元のCSVファイル　"test.CSV"　 A, 100, test　　　があるとします．
2列目の値を10~0に変更し，計11個のCSVを新たに出力するために，
以下のプログラムを作成しました．

```
require 'csv'

# CSVを読み込んで二次元配列にする
array = CSV.read('filepath\test.csv')
puts(array.to_s)

# x=ループ処理回数
x =10
while x >= 0 

    array[0][1]= x

    #,ごとに分割して出力
    strAry = array.to_s.split(",")

    #保存するファイル名
    #配列1行目を取得
    y = array[0][0]
    file_name = y.to_s + "+" + x.to_s + '.csv'

    s = strAry.to_csv
    p s
    File.write(file_name, s)

    x = x - 1
end
```

上記を実行すると，A+0.csv ～A+10.csvまでの計11個のファイルが作成されます．
(出力ファイルに [[" が含まれてしまうなど不完全ですが，ここまでは作成できました．)

これを応用して，元のCSVファイル(3行)
"test2.CSV"　 A1, 100, test
　　　　　　　　　A2, 100, test
　　　　　　　　　A3, 100, test
がある場合に，各行の2列目に数字を割り当てるファイルを作成したいと考えています，
例えば，6を割り当てる場合，
　A1　A2　A3
　 6　　0　　0
　 5　　1　　0
　 5　　0　　1
　 4　　2　　0
　 4　　0　　2
　 4　　1　　1
　　　 　・
　　　　 ・
　 1　　0　　5
　 0　　1　　5
　 0　　0　　6　(3H6= 28通り)

計28個のCSVファイルを作成したいと考えています．

例：1個目の出力ファイル　"A1_600.csv"
　　内容
　A1, 6, test
　A2, 0, test
　A3, 0, test
例：2個目の出力ファイル　"A1_510.csv"
　　内容
　A1, 5, test
　A2, 1, test
　A3, 0, test

この場合のコードの書き方をご教示頂ければ幸いです．

**追加情報**
　
実際にはA1...A6まで用意し，最初の質問文以上の数(5)を割り当てようとしています．
　
A1　A2　A3　A4　A5　A6
5　　0　　0 　  0　　0　　0
4　　1　　0 　  0　　0　　0
4　　0　　1 　  0　　0　　0  
　 　　　 　・
　　　　 　 ・
0　　0　　0 　  0　　0　  4  (6H5= 252通り)

252通りなら，ゴリ押しでもいけるように思います．
今回，私が実行していることは，

"test3.CSV"

A1, 0, test
A2, 0, test
A3, 0, test
A4, 0, test
A5, 0, test
A6, 0, test
B1, 0, test
B2, 0, test
B3, 0, test
B4, 0, test
B5, 0, test
B6, 0, test
C1, 0, test
C2, 0, test
C3, 0, test
C4, 0, test
D1, 0, test
　　　 　・
　　　　 ・
おそらく，合計44行程度

を用意した場合に，
A 6,0,0,0,0,0 (252通り)
B 6,0,0,0,0,0 (252通り)
C 6,0,0,0 (56通り)
D …

252×252×56… 通りのCSVファイルを作成しようとしています．
そうなると，ゴリ押しではおそらく難しく，
別の方法を検討する必要があるかもしれません．

**追加情報2**

元の管理ファイル"test3.csv" 例
[image: 元の管理ファイル"test3.csv" 例]

変更したいのは緑色，太枠で囲った部分のみです．
1,2列目のTEST,A はお伝えしやすくするために記載してありますが，
値の変更は行いません．
　
この場合，出力CSVは
タイトル　"A500000_B50000_C5000_D5000_E500_F500~.csv"
となるのが理想です．

"A500000_B50000_C5000_D5000_E500_F500~.csv"
"A410000_B50000_C5000_D5000_E500_F500~.csv"
　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　・
"A000005_B00005_C0005_D0005_E005_F005~.csv"

ファイル数は，252*252*56*56*21*...　出来上がる．という感じです．

元の管理ファイル"test3.csv"内のA,B,C,D~の行数は変更しないため，
地道にループ処理をしていくという方法でも良いように考えます．

Comment: `「2列目の値を10~0に変更し」` となっていますが、`array[0][2] = x` としているので、3列目になるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: argusさん，コメントをありがとうございます．
 
array[0][2]= x　ではなく，array[0][1]= x の間違いでした．
修正させていただきます．

Comment: そもそもこの処理はどういう目的で必要になるんでしょうか？仕様がややこしく馴染みがないものなので、目的や背景を理解しておいた方が解法のイメージがつきやすくなる気がします。

Comment: @Junichi Itoさん，お世話になっております．説明不足について，申し訳ありません．　
あるシミュレーションソフトがあり，CSVには個体数などのパラメータを記述して読み込ませることで，シミュレーションを実行できます．今回割り当てをしている数字がその"個体数"に相当します．パラメータを変化させて何千通りの
シナリオを実行，結果の比較をしようと考えています．
しかし何千・何万個のCSVをそれぞれ値を変えて作成する，というのは手作業では厳しいため，今回Rubyを利用しようと考えました．
　
CSVを大量生成する方法を２通り考えました．
1つは，１行のみ記述したCSVをいくつも用意し，組み合わせで結合していく方法．もう1つは管理リストを作成し，パラメータを重複組み合わせで割り振り，CSVを大量に作成する方法．作成後の管理のしやすさを考え，今回は後者を選択しました．

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。なんとなく背景がわかりました。あと、test3.csvではB1やC1が出てきますが、これはどのように出力されるのでしょうか？A1とは扱いを変える必要があるんでしょうか？出力例を追記してもらえると助かります。

Comment: @Junichi Itoさん　お世話になっております．情報を追記させていただきました．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえず「ゴリ押し実装」で作ってみました。
組み合わせの作成は「ループで回しながら合致するものを抽出」というロジックになっています。
この質問の個数ぐらいであれば問題にはならないですが、もっと個数が増えると非常に遅くなるかもしれません。（が、増える見込みがないのであれば、これでもいいのでは？と思います）

以下、実装とテストコード（RSpec）です。

```
require 'csv'
require 'spec_helper'

class CombinationCsv
  def self.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, assigned_number, col_size)
    input_arrays = CSV.read(input_path)
    generate_combination(assigned_number, col_size).each do |numbers|
      output_path = File.join(output_dir, "A1_#{numbers.join}.csv")
      CSV.open(output_path, 'w') do |csv|
        input_arrays.each_with_index do |input_cols, i|
          output_cols = input_cols.dup
          output_cols.each(&:strip!)
          output_cols[1] = numbers[i]
          csv << output_cols
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # ゴリ押し実装なので、もっとスマートなロジックがあるはず
  def self.generate_combination(assigned_number, col_size)
    max = "#{assigned_number}#{'0' * (col_size - 1)}".to_i
    (assigned_number..max).map { |number|
      target = number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+) == assigned_number
      number.to_s.rjust(3, '0').chars.map(&:to_i) if target
    }.compact
  end
end

describe CombinationCsv do
  describe '::generate_csv' do
    let(:input_dir) { File.expand_path('../input', __FILE__) }
    let(:input_path) { File.join(input_dir, 'test2.csv') }
    let(:output_dir) { File.expand_path('../output', __FILE__) }

    def output_files
      Dir.glob(File.join(output_dir, '*.csv'))
    end

    before do
      FileUtils.rm(output_files)
    end
    example do
      expect {
        CombinationCsv.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, 6, 3)
      }.to change { output_files.size }.from(0).to(28)

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A1_600.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 6 test),
                               %w(A2 0 test),
                               %w(A3 0 test)
                           ])

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A1_510.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 5 test),
                               %w(A2 1 test),
                               %w(A3 0 test)
                           ])
    end
  end

  describe '::generate_combination' do
    let(:expected) do
      [
          [6, 0, 0],
          [5, 1, 0],
          [5, 0, 1],
          [4, 2, 0],
          [4, 0, 2],
          [4, 1, 1],
          [3, 3, 0],
          [3, 0, 3],
          [3, 2, 1],
          [3, 1, 2],
          [2, 4, 0],
          [2, 0, 4],
          [2, 3, 1],
          [2, 1, 3],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [1, 5, 0],
          [1, 0, 5],
          [1, 4, 1],
          [1, 1, 4],
          [1, 3, 2],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [0, 6, 0],
          [0, 0, 6],
          [0, 5, 1],
          [0, 1, 5],
          [0, 4, 2],
          [0, 2, 4],
          [0, 3, 3]
      ]
    end
    example do
      result = CombinationCsv.generate_combination(6, 3)
      expect(result).to contain_exactly(*expected)
    end
  end
end
```

Githubにもコードをアップしているので、手元で動かすことも可能です。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/combination-csv

以上、ご参考までに。

#### EDIT

最初のバージョンだと10以上の数を割り当てたときにおかしくなるので、ロジックを修正しました。

```
require 'csv'
require 'spec_helper'

class CombinationCsv
  def self.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, assigned_number, col_size)
    input_arrays = CSV.read(input_path)
    generate_combination(assigned_number, col_size).each do |numbers|
      output_path = File.join(output_dir, "A1_#{numbers.join}.csv")
      CSV.open(output_path, 'w') do |csv|
        input_arrays.each_with_index do |input_cols, i|
          output_cols = input_cols.dup
          output_cols.each(&:strip!)
          output_cols[1] = numbers[i]
          csv << output_cols
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.generate_combination(assigned_number, col_size)
    return [assigned_number] if col_size == 1
    assigned_number.downto(0).each_with_object([]) do |n, result|
      next_number = assigned_number - n
      child_results = generate_combination(next_number, col_size - 1)
      child_results.each do |numbers|
        result << [n, *numbers]
      end
    end
  end
end

describe CombinationCsv do
  describe '::generate_csv' do
    let(:input_dir) { File.expand_path('../input', __FILE__) }
    let(:input_path) { File.join(input_dir, 'test2.csv') }
    let(:output_dir) { File.expand_path('../output', __FILE__) }

    def output_files
      Dir.glob(File.join(output_dir, '*.csv'))
    end

    before do
      FileUtils.rm(output_files)
    end
    example do
      expect {
        CombinationCsv.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, 6, 3)
      }.to change { output_files.size }.from(0).to(28)

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A1_600.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 6 test),
                               %w(A2 0 test),
                               %w(A3 0 test)
                           ])

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A1_510.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 5 test),
                               %w(A2 1 test),
                               %w(A3 0 test)
                           ])
    end
  end

  describe '::generate_combination' do
    let(:expected) do
      [
          [6, 0, 0],
          [5, 1, 0],
          [5, 0, 1],
          [4, 2, 0],
          [4, 0, 2],
          [4, 1, 1],
          [3, 3, 0],
          [3, 0, 3],
          [3, 2, 1],
          [3, 1, 2],
          [2, 4, 0],
          [2, 0, 4],
          [2, 3, 1],
          [2, 1, 3],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [1, 5, 0],
          [1, 0, 5],
          [1, 4, 1],
          [1, 1, 4],
          [1, 3, 2],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [0, 6, 0],
          [0, 0, 6],
          [0, 5, 1],
          [0, 1, 5],
          [0, 4, 2],
          [0, 2, 4],
          [0, 3, 3]
      ]
    end
    example do
      result = CombinationCsv.generate_combination(6, 3)
      expect(result).to contain_exactly(*expected)
    end

    context 'assigned_number is 10' do
      let(:expected) do
        [
          [10, 0],
          [9, 1],
          [8, 2],
          [7, 3],
          [6, 4],
          [5, 5],
          [4, 6],
          [3, 7],
          [2, 8],
          [1, 9],
          [0, 10]
        ]
      end
      example do
        result = CombinationCsv.generate_combination(10 ,2)
        expect(result).to contain_exactly(*expected)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

コードはこちらにも置いています。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/combination-csv/tree/not-loop

#### EDIT2

A, B, Cといったグループごとに組み合わせを作り、さらにそれを掛け合わせてそれぞれ別ファイルとして出力する場合のサンプルコードを作ってみました。
テストコードで使っているtest3-1.csvはA1,A2,B1,B2,C1の5行で、割り当てる数字は2です。
3x3x1で9通りのファイルが生成されます。

```
require 'csv'
require 'spec_helper'

class CombinationCsv
  def self.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, assigned_number)
    input_arrays = CSV.read(input_path)
    all_combinations = generate_all_combinations(input_arrays, assigned_number)
    all_combinations.each do |combination|
      file_name = combination.map { |k, v| "#{k}#{v.join}" }.join('_') + '.csv'
      output_path = File.join(output_dir, file_name)
      CSV.open(output_path, 'w') do |csv|
        numbers = combination.values.flatten
        write_csv_rows(csv, input_arrays, numbers)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.generate_all_combinations(input_arrays, assigned_number)
    count_by_group = generate_count_by_group(input_arrays)
    combination_hash = generate_combination_by_group(count_by_group, assigned_number)
    all_arrays = combination_hash.values
    first = all_arrays.shift
    all_combinations = first.product(*all_arrays)
    names = combination_hash.keys
    all_combinations.map {|combinations| names.zip(combinations).to_h }
  end

  def self.generate_combination_by_group(count_by_group, assigned_number)
    count_by_group.map {|name, count|
      [name, generate_combination(assigned_number, count)]
    }.to_h
  end

  def self.generate_count_by_group(input_arrays)
    name_and_numbers = input_arrays.map{|cols|
      /(?<name>[A-Z]+)(?<number>\d+)/ =~ cols.first
      [name, number.to_i]
    }
    groups_by_name = name_and_numbers.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(name, number), hash|
      hash[name] << number
    end
    groups_by_name.map{|name, values| [name, values.max]}.to_h
  end

  def self.write_csv_rows(csv, input_arrays, numbers)
    input_arrays.each_with_index do |input_cols, i|
      csv << input_cols.dup.tap do |output_cols|
        output_cols.each(&:strip!)
        output_cols[1] = numbers[i]
      end
    end
  end

  def self.generate_combination(assigned_number, col_size)
    return [[assigned_number]] if col_size == 1
    assigned_number.downto(0).flat_map do |n|
      child_results = generate_combination(assigned_number - n, col_size - 1)
      child_results.map { |numbers| [n, *numbers] }
    end
  end
end

describe CombinationCsv do
  describe '::generate_csv' do
    let(:input_dir) { File.expand_path('../input', __FILE__) }
    let(:input_path) { File.join(input_dir, 'test3-1.csv') }
    let(:output_dir) { File.expand_path('../output', __FILE__) }

    def output_files
      Dir.glob(File.join(output_dir, '*.csv'))
    end

    before do
      FileUtils.rm(output_files)
    end
    example do
      expect {
        CombinationCsv.generate_csv(input_path, output_dir, 2)
      }.to change { output_files.size }.from(0).to(9)

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A20_B20_C2.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 2 test),
                               %w(A2 0 test),
                               %w(B1 2 test),
                               %w(B2 0 test),
                               %w(C1 2 test),
                           ])

      output_path = File.join(output_dir, 'A02_B02_C2.csv')
      result = CSV.read(output_path)
      expect(result).to eq([
                               %w(A1 0 test),
                               %w(A2 2 test),
                               %w(B1 0 test),
                               %w(B2 2 test),
                               %w(C1 2 test),
                           ])
    end
  end

  # 以下省略
end
```

ソースコードはこちらにあります。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/combination-csv/blob/multiple-output/spec/combination_csv_spec.rb

実際にやろうとしているのはこれよりももっと大きな組み合わせのようですが、252*252*56*56*21を計算するだけでも4,182,119,424(400億以上！)のファイルが作成されることになります。
これだけのファイルを一気に作成しようとすると、普通のPCでは処理能力の限界を超えてしまいそうです。（怖いので試していません）

なので、そもそものアプローチを変える必要があるんじゃ無いかと思います。

Comment: Junichi Itoさん
　
丁寧なコメント・ご回答をありがとうございます．
質問に情報を追記しました．

Comment: Junichi Itoさん 　 まずは，どのような処理を行っているのかを理解するところから始めてみます．

Comment: Junichi Itoさん　お世話になっております．まずは複数の丁寧なご回答にお礼申し上げます．実は，Railsをインストールしてコードの実行を試みたのですが...恥ずかしながら，未だに実行できておりません．おそらくdescribeメソッド等はRailsを用いた定義だと思うのですが，Railsを用いない場合の記述方法がありましたら，ご教示いただければ，と思います．

Comment: Railsは使っていません。RSpecを使っています。Rubyはおそらく2.1以上が必須だと思います。実行方法は[README](https://github.com/JunichiIto/combination-csv)に書いてあるとおりです。bundleコマンドが見つからない場合は `gem install bundler` してください。あと、EDIT2のコードはmultiple-outputというブランチにあるので注意してください。

Comment: Junichi Itoさん　お世話になっております．返信が遅くなり，申し訳ありません．その後，RSpecをインストール後，無事に実行ができました．大変感謝しております．現在は，値やコードの順番を変え，どのように記述されているのかを理解している最中です．他のアプローチを検討していますが，それと並行して試してみようと，何万個かのファイルを生成ごとにフォルダ分けをする，というコードを記述するために試行錯誤しています．

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか。ちょっとややこしい箇所はコメントを付けてますので参考にしてください。
全体的に「Array祭り」みたいな作りになってますので、見慣れないメソッドは適宜お調べになってみてください。

```ruby
require 'csv'

class CombinationCsvGenerator
  def initialize(src_path, total)
    @src = CSV.read(src_path).each { |columns| columns.each(&:strip!) }
    @total = total
    @rows = @src.size
  end

  def generate(dest_path)
    combination.each do |numbers|
      filepath = File.join(dest_path, "A1_#{numbers.join}.csv")
      # 元ネタ(@src)と組み合わせ数字(numbers)を組み合わせて、２列目だけをすり替える
      body = @src.zip(numbers).map {|columns| columns.flatten.values_at(0, -1, 2..-2) }
      output filepath, body
    end
  end

  private

  def combination
    # 重複順列を作成し、合計値が指定した値になるもののみselectする
    (0..@total).to_a
      .repeated_permutation(@rows)
      .select { |values| values.reduce(:+) == @total }
  end

  def output(path, body)
    CSV.open(path, 'w') do |csv|
      body.each { |columns| csv << columns }
    end
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $0
  generator = CombinationCsvGenerator.new('test2.csv', 6)
  generator.generate('output/')
end
```

Comment: @itmammothさん　ご回答・プログラム内へのコメントをありがとうございます．適宜，検索しつつ理解を深めていきます．　今回は２列目の値変更でしたが，例えば５列目を変更したい場合，どの部分を変更すれば良いのでしょうか．いくつか値を変更してみましたが，思い通りに実行できていません．

Answer (score 1):

ruby は不案内なのでアルゴリズムの説明だけします。

A1, A2, A3 に 6を割り当てる場合を例に説明します。これは A1, A2, A3 という三つの箱に 6つのボールを、個々のボールは区別せずに割り振る問題と同じです。これを解くために、ボールを一列に並べ、さらに三つに分けるために仕切りを二つ、S1 と S2 を用意します。仕切りをボールの間に置き三つに分けたら、一番左の組を A1 に、真ん中を A2 に、一番右を A3 に入れます。例えば ボールを O で表すと、

```
O S1 O O S2 O O O
```

の場合はA1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 = 3 で、

```
O O S1 S2 0 0 0 0
```

の場合は A1 = 2, A2 = 0, A3 = 4 になります。

仕切りの置ける場所は、一番左、個々のボールの間、一番右の、合計 ７ヶ所です。この ７ヶ所に置く、仕切りの置き方をすべて数え上げれば、三つの箱へのボールの割り振り方がすべて求められることになります。ただし、仕切りを単に入れ替えただけの場合は重複してしまうので、S2 は S1 の左には来ないという制約が必要になります。

具体的には、まず仕切りを二つとも左端に置き、S2 を一つずつ右に動かしていきます。

```
A1 A2 A3
 0  0  6   S1 S2 O O O O O O
 0  1  5   S1 O S2 O O O O O
 0  2  4   S1 O O S2 O O O O
...
 0  6  0   S1 O O O O O O S2
```

これで仕切り S1 が一番左、つまり A1 が 0 の場合がすべて求まりました。

次に S1 を一つ右に動かします。S2 は 、S1 の左には来れないので S1 と同じ場所に置き、前と同じように一つずつ右に動かしていきます。

```
A1 A2 A3
 1  0  5   O S1 S2 O O O O O
 1  1  4   O S1 O S2 O O O O
...
 1  5  0   O S1 O O O O O S2
```

これで A1 が 1 の場合がすべて求まりました。

このように S1 を一つ右に動かしては S2 を動かし、ということを繰り返し、最後に

```
A1 A2 A3
 6  0  0   O O O O O O S1 S2
```

となったところで終わりです。

以上を擬似コードで表すと、

```
for S1 = 0 to 6 do
  for S2 = S1 to 6 do
    A1 = S1
    A2 = S2 - S1
    A3 = 6 - S2
  end for
end for
```

A1...A6 に 5 を割り当てる場合は

```
for S1 = 0 to 5 do
  for S2 = S1 to 5 do
    for S3 = S2 to 5 do
      for S4 = S3 to 5 do
        for S5 = S4 to 5 do
          A1 = S1
          A2 = S2 - S1
          A3 = S3 - S2
          A4 = S4 - S3
          A5 = S5 - S4
          A6 = 5 - S5
        end for
      end for
    end for
  end for
end for
```

です。

この方法なら、きっちり必要な回数だけの繰り返しになるので、速く求められると思います。
任意の個数の A に、任意の数を割り当てられるようにするのも、少し面倒ですができます。

ただ Junichi Ito さんもおっしゃっているように、252*252*56*56*21 はほぼ 4G です。test ファイルが 1 block しか使わなくても、1block 1k バイトとしても、4Tバイトのディスク容量が必要になります。また 1秒間に1000 ファイル処理したとしても、4G 個だと 50日近く掛かる計算になります。

ファイルを経由せずに、パラメータを生成しては、シミュレーションのモジュールに直接渡せるなら、そっちの方がいいような気がします。

Comment: @Hidekiさん　コメントが遅くなり，申し訳ありません．大変分かりやすいアルゴリズムの説明をありがとうございます．く，理解出来ました．　>ファイルを経由せずに～　仰る通りで，相当，特異であると思います．別の方法が可能であれば，そちらを検討すべきですね…